# How to use the image constructor in React?

Tags: reactjs

How do I display the image created by the image constructor in React?

I've used the image constructor to preload images but I'm not sure if when I load in the markup the same image is being used that has been fetched. Is the `new Image` created and then displayed through the cache and sought by reference to `src`?

I'm working off instructions as below for preloading:

```
    this.props.pictures.forEach((picture) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = picture.fileName;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an `Image` object gives you the equivalent of having `<img src="filename">` but it won't show up anywhere unless you put it in your DOM somewhere. So it's up to you where you place the images. If you want them in a particular `div` of your document you will need to locate it and append the new `img` object using `div.appendChild(img)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Im = new Image();
Im.src = picture.fileName;
let div = document.querySelector("id");
div.appendChild(Im)
```